# XPath query from a node when searching in another node

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, nodes

Suppose I have an XML tree as below:

```
Amazon
   -ASIN
   -Items
      -ItemAttributes
         -author
         -title
         -pages
```

I'm trying to show the ASIN numbers where the author is J.K. Rowling. Tried:

```
//Items/Item/ItemAttributes[Author="J.K. Rowling"]/ASIN
```

but it doesn't work. Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you add source sample as **XML**? Also clarify what you mean by *it doesn't work* - it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
/Amazon[Items/ItemAttributes/author="J.K. Rowling"]/ASIN
```

will return `ASIN` element children of `Amazon` elements that have descendant `author` elements with string values equal to `"J.K. Rowling"`.

Note: Capitalization must match -- your XML outline uses lower-case `author` while your XPath example uses capitalized `Author`.